# Trying to display random data from a local json file I created, but getting an undefined error in render

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I am learning React and right now I am trying to get my app to display a random joke (both question and answer) from the JSON file I created.  However, I get the following error: **getRandomJoke is not defined.** I figured since it's a function, getRandomJoke does not need to get defined. Can someone explain where my mistake is and why I am getting this error?

This is the local JSON file I created:
**SportsJokesData.js**

```
 const SportsJokesData = [
            {
                id: "1",
                question: "What did the baseball glove say to the ball?",
                answer: "Catch ya later!"

            },
            {
                id: "2",
                question: "What are the rules for zebra baseball?",
                answer: "Three stripes and you’re out."

            },
            {
                id: "3",
                question: "Why are umpires always overweight?",
                answer: "It’s their job to clean their plates."

            }

        export default SportsJokesData;
```

This is the component I created to get it displayed on my browser, **SportsJokesApi.JS:**

```
import React from 'react'
import SportsJokesData from './SportsJokesData';

class SportsJokesApi extends React.Component {

    getRandomJoke(){
       return SportsJokesData[(SportsJokesData.length * Math.random()) << 0]

    }

    render() {
        return (
            <p>{getRandomJoke}</p>
        )
        }
    }
          export default SportsJokesApi;
```

Answer (score 1):

Do `<p>{this.getRandomJoke()}</p>` inside your `render()`